# Re-init a clean Gerrit but I want Gerrit to use my previous configuration settings

Tags: gerrit

I've messed up my Gerrit installation. So I want to re-init Gerrit.
I tried to do:

```
java -jar gerrit-2.15.1.war init -d /my_gerrit_destination
```

and Gerrit asked if I wanted to use my previous settings. Perfect!

But.. I've messed up some file in the /index-folder so my initialization failed.

Is it possible to clean all or some of the directories/files and Gerrit will still ask me if I wanted to use same configurations as before?
I ask because the person that holds some of the used passwords in the config, is on vacation.

**EDIT**:

1.I removed the index directory.

2.I ran the above init command again.

3.Gerrit FAILED to start

4.Checked in the error.log and followed instructions about re-index some directories but got an error posted in error.log:

```
[2018-07-04 14:39:39,989] [main] WARN  com.google.gerrit.sshd.SshDaemon : Cannot format SSHD host key [EdDSA]: invalid key type
[2018-07-04 14:39:40,006] [main] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.config.GitwebCgiConfig : gitweb not installed (no /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi found)
[2018-07-04 14:39:41,069] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log : Logging initialized @11300ms
[2018-07-04 14:39:41,161] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.git.LocalDiskRepositoryManager : Defaulting core.streamFileThreshold to 1339m
[2018-07-04 14:39:41,635] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Loading plugins from /opt/gerrit/plugins
[2018-07-04 14:39:41,745] [main] ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No index versions for index 'groups' ready; run java -jar /opt/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war reindex --index groups

1 error
        at com.google.gerrit.server.index.VersionManager.initIndex(VersionManager.java:173)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.index.VersionManager.start(VersionManager.java:94)
        at com.google.gerrit.lifecycle.LifecycleManager.start(LifecycleManager.java:92)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:349)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:256)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.AbstractProgram.main(AbstractProgram.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.invokeProgram(GerritLauncher.java:223)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.mainImpl(GerritLauncher.java:119)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.main(GerritLauncher.java:63)
        at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

5.I tried to run `java -jar /opt/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war reindex --index groups` but I get

```
`fatal: not a Gerrit site: '.'
fatal: Perhaps you need to run init first?`
```

6.New init fails to start Gerrit.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the index directory?

Comment: Hi again Marcelo. I tried it after your question and followed some instruction about re-indexing. But when I try "java -jar /opt/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war reindex --index groups" I get the error-> "fatal: not a Gerrit site: '.'
fatal: Perhaps you need to run init first?" I ran the above java -jar gerrit.war init mygerrit, but that didn't solve it.

Comment: Add to the question the error you get when you execute the Gerrit init.

Comment: I hope it makes sense. Should I delete everything in the cashe directory? I answered No in the init process.

Comment: I solved it! I removed the index directory again. But I immediately ran the command "java -jar /opt/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war reindex --index" for all that should be in the directory, that means -> changes, groups and accounts. And then i was able to restart Gerrit! So something broke if i did run the init in between.

Comment: I'll update the question with my answer. But it was you @MarceloÁviladeOliveira that pointed me to the right way.

Comment: Great! I added an answer to the question. This could help others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove the index directory

```
rm -rf GERRIT-SITE/index
```

2) Run the reindex command

```
java -jar gerrit-VERSION.war reindex -d GERRIT-SITE
```

Comment: This was correct! People should just have in mind that they use their own gerrit version install.

Comment: I just adjusted the answer.